# Get object details from clrstack output in windbg

Tags: c#, .net, clr, windbg

I have a multi-threaded .NET application that hangs on an OnUserPreferenceChanged event. This is typically caused by a UI control or message loop started on a background thread (see e.g. http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html), but as far as I can tell that isn't the case here. I verified this by setting a breakpoint in the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext (as suggested here http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2008/12/15/debugging-ui/) and it is only constructed once, in the main UI thread.

Here's the output from !clrstack in windbg:

> 0013eea8 7c90e514 [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 0013eea8]
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle,
>   UInt32, Boolean, Boolean) 0013ef54 792b68af
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int64, Boolean) 0013ef70 792b6865
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean) 0013ef84 7b6f1a4f
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(System.Threading.WaitHandle)
>   0013ef98 7ba2d68b
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean) 0013f038 7b6f33ac
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
>   0013f06c 7b920bd7
>   System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,
>   System.Object) 0013f084 7a92ed62
>   Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents+SystemEventInvokeInfo.Invoke(Boolean,
>   System.Object[]) 0013f0b8 7a92dc8f
>   Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.RaiseEvent(Boolean, System.Object,
>   System.Object[]) 0013f104 7a92e227
>   Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.OnUserPreferenceChanged(Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr) 0013f124 7aaa06ec
>   Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

The last method I can get param info on is:

> 0013f084 7a92ed62
>   Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents+SystemEventInvokeInfo.Invoke(Boolean,
>   System.Object[])
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x01404420
>           checkFinalization = 0x00000001
>           args = 0x0144a298

Here's my question: How can I get more information here? Ultimately, I'd like to know which objects and/or threads this Invoke is for. Something like "!do 0x01404420" or "!do 0x0144a298" but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Search for exceptions in the heap by using !dumpheap -type Exception.

Also you can see the value of variables in a  class,which will be useful to understand the state of the class. Use !dumpheap -type ClassName. You will get a MT(Method Table) address. From MT address see the Object address. Use !do address to dump the class.

Use [!syncblk](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/01/09/a-hang-scenario-locks-and-critical-sections.aspx) to see the locked threads

Comment: That's good info but in this case I have a known deadlock scenario: Thread 0 is waiting to invoke OnUserPreferenceChanged event to some other thread. I just need to know which thread it's invoking to.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding problems caused by SystemEvents class and in particular OnUserPreferenceChanged event try to use the CheckSystemEventsHandlersForFreeze() function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52721562/901333) which can help to find root cause, i.e. which controls was created on wrong thread and thus causing freeze.